# Как подключиться снаружи к postgres в докер-контейнере?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Столкнулся с проблемой подключения к докер-контейнеру с крутящейся в нем базой данных postgres по логину и паролю. Ниже кусок кода в docker-compose, который поднимает postgres базу данных.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - docker/.env
```

В файле переменных окружения передаю DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER и так далее:

```
DB_NAME=movies
POSTGRES_USER=my_name
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
DB_DEV_HOST=localhost
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
```

При попытке подключения через логин/пароль выкидывает ошибку, что такого пользователя нету. Как правильно решить эту проблему?

Это выглядит следующим образом:
при выполнении команды

`psql -U my_name` выкидывается ошибка

`psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "my_name" does not exist`

Comment: Может я вопроса не понял: я передаю данные окружения, это разве не запускает базу данных с указанными переменными?

Answer (score 1):

`docker ps` посмотрите ваши запущенные приложения (postgres должен быть в статусе Up)
Примерный вывод:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
0bbe469daff4   postgres:13.3                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 months ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   <postgres_name_container>
```

Далее команда

`docker exec -it <postgres_name_container> psql -U <user_name>`
Это вход через контейнер (по сути можно зайти подобной командой в баш оболочку и далее `psql ...` )

Еще вариант:

`docker inspect <postgres_name_container>` покажет всю инфу о запущенном контейнере включая его реальный адресс (пример `..."IPAddress": "172.22.0.1"...`)
Тогда подключение по этому адресу выполняется

`psql -h 172.22.0.1 -U <user_name> -d <database name>`

Comment: Контейнер запущен. Указанная вами команда приводит к ошибке: psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "my_name" does not exist

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян тогда явно передайте ` database` через флаг `-d`. `docker exec -it <postgres_name_container> psql -U <user_name> -d <database_name>`

Comment: Вот это помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь подключиться к локальному инстансу PG, а не к тому что в контейнере.

При подключении нужно дополнительно указать хост(-h) и порт(-p).

Из ошибки видно что psql пытается подключиться через сокет, но вы его прокинули через volume(и врядли это нужно).